# AngularJs ui-router onEnter firing before the view loads

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a couple of nested views. The Html is as follows.
For the index page:

```
<section ui-view id="one"></section>
```

Then I have my second nested view, which looks like this:

```
<!--- Removed for brevity --->

<section ui-view="two" id="two"></section>
```

And finally I have another nested view that looks like this:

```
<!--- Removed for brevity --->

<section ui-view="three" id="three"></section>
```

So, the routes; they look like this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home.one', configureOneRoute());

function configureOneRoute() {
    return {
        url: ':categoryName/one',
        views: {
            '@': {
                templateUrl: 'scripts/one/one.html',
                controller: 'StepOneController',
                controllerAs: 'controller'
            }
        },
        params: {
            clear: false
        },
        resolve: {
            options: getOptions,
            category: getCategory,
            criteria: getCriteria,
            groups: getGroups,
            priorityColours: getPriorityColours,
            products: getProducts,
            questions: getQuestions,
            settings: getSettings,
            createSession: createSession,
            applyQuestions: applyQuestions,
            updateSession: updateSession
        },
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'Step one'
        },
        onEnter: function (products) {            
            console.log(products);      
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('#two').offset().top
            }, 2000);
        }
    };
};
```

Then I have my second route:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home.one.two', configureTwoRoute());

function configureTwoRoute() {
    return {
        url: '/two',
        views: {
            'two': {
                templateUrl: 'scripts/two/two.html',
                controller: 'StepTwoController',
                controllerAs: 'controller'
            }
        },
        resolve: {
            updateSession: updateSession
        },
        data: {
            requireLogin: true,
            pageTitle: 'Step two'
        },
        onEnter: function (products) {            
            console.log(products);      
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('#two').offset().top
            }, 2000);
        }
    };
};
```

and finally my third view:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home.one.two.three', configureThreeRoute());

function configureThreeRoute() {
    return {
        url: '/three',
        views: {
            'three': {
                templateUrl: 'scripts/three/three.html',
                controller: 'StepThreeController',
                controllerAs: 'controller'
            }
        },
        resolve: {
            updateSession: updateSession
        },
        data: {
            requireLogin: true,
            pageTitle: 'Step three'
        },
        onEnter: function (products) {            
            console.log(products);      
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('#three').offset().top
            }, 2000);
        }
    };
};
```

If I navigate to each view, it works fine. but if I am on step two and refresh the page, I get this error:

> Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

And I know it's because the first view hasn't loaded yet, but the resolve has. Because of this, the `ui-view` for "two" doesn't exist and therefore you can't scroll to it.

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: does this happen on all the views, or just step two?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a race condition on refresh. Try either putting that code in a timeout or putting it in the mapped controller.

From the docs it doesn't looks like its guaranteed that the page will be rendered, just that the state is active:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like onEnter is being called what it's supposed to be called - when entering this state. If you want an event that is called when the view is loaded you can give `"$viewContentLoaded"` a try. See further at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#view-load-events